# How to receive UDP datagrams with VB.NET UDPClient

Tags: vb.net, network-programming

I am building a simple test program for some embedded devices. They are controlled through Wi-Fi using UDP multicast messages. The test application, written using VB.NET is able to send data to the devices but I am not able to receive data back from them.

The data from the embedded devices is captured by WireShark correctly, but nothing is received by the test program.

Windows Firewall is open for the program, any port, any IP for UDP.

This is the thread code I have as a skeleton to receive the data:

```
 Private Sub ListenForInput()
    Try
        Dim udpClient As New UdpClient(port)
        Dim grpEndpoint As New IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port)

        While keepListening
            Debug.Print("Listening on IP:" + ipAddress.ToString + " port:" + port.ToString)
            Dim input As Byte() = udpClient.Receive(grpEndpoint)
            Debug.Print("Got data")
        End While

    Catch ex As SocketException
        '
        ' What do do?
        '
        Debug.Print("Oops!")
    End Try
End Sub
```

The Debug output displays the "listening" message, but the call to Receive never returns.

Comment: You need to join the multicast group. It's not like (obsolete) broadcast, multicast is only used if you actually subscribe to it.

Comment: @RonMaupin, many thanks, I had forgotten that. Works like a charm!